# Print preview freeze intervals in javaScript

Tags: javascript, printing, intervals, freeze

I have a problem with method `mywindow,print();` cause when print preview is open my intervals in JavaScript files  stops. My code is :

```js
function pri() {

  var mywindow = window.open('bileta.html', 'hello', 'height=400,width=600');
  mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title></title>');
  mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
  mywindow.document.write('<h1></h1>');
  mywindow.document.write(document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML);
  mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

  mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
  mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10*/

  mywindow.print();
  mywindow.close();

  return true;
}
```

I've searched in google and stalckoverflow but all the answers were about the chrome version and I use a chrome version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit).

So what I'm asking is that is any way to print and my print preview page not freeze my JavaScript intervals?

Comment: Have you tried with  [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) ?

Comment: @R3tep no i haven't, do you mean to make my intervals with `requestAnimationFrame` ?

Comment: Also it freeze my other JavaScript Functions too

Comment: I believe window.print() blocks Javascript's single thread. Perhaps you could try putting the Javascript you wish to keep running in a web worker?

Comment: you can't close it until after it prints

Comment: @BlinkingCahill i tried and my code:
` window.onload =function startWorker() {
            if (typeof (Worker) !== "undefined") {
                if (typeof (w) == "undefined") {
                    w = new Worker("userpg.js");
                }
                w.onmessage = function (event) {
                    document.getElementById("gr").innerHTML = event.data;
                };
            } else {
                document.getElementById("gr").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Workers...";
            }
        }`

Comment: @BlinkingCahill is this the right way because my intervals still get blocked from print preview window

Comment: You are on the right path - your interval should be in the worker and be self.setInterval() and not window.setInterval(). I can certainly keep a console.log running in my web worker - manipulating the dom might be the problem or receiving the message.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment above I believe the single thread of Javascript is blocked by the window.print() call you are making so a normal interval you set will pause.

A web worker opens a second thread up, that can still keep it running. My script looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>

        <p>Press to <a href="javascript:pri()">print</a>!</p>
        <p id="countup">Count</p>

        <script>

            window.onload = function() {
                if (window.Worker) {
                    var myWorker = new Worker('worker.js');
                    myWorker.onmessage = function(msg) {
                        console.log(msg.data);
                        document.getElementById('countup').innerHTML = msg.data;
                    };
                }
            }

            function pri() {
                var mywindow = window.open('bileta.html', 'hello', 'height=400,width=600');
                mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title></title>');
                mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
                mywindow.document.write('<h1 id="hello">Hello</h1>');
                mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

                mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
                mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10*/

                mywindow.print();
                mywindow.close();

                return true;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the worker.js script looks like this:

```
function counter() {

    var count = 0;

    self.setInterval(function() {
        postMessage('counter =' + count);
        count++;
    }, 100);

 }

 counter();
```

Of course printing involves interacting with the browser and OS so results may vary. This script works with Chrome, IE11, Edge on Windows 10 but not Firefox (perhaps somebody could post a comment fixing that.)

See these two articles for more information on web workers:

[MDN Using Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)

[Basics of Web Workers](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what about the target origin ?

Comment: Sorry I don't know what you mean by "target origin"?

Comment: Thanks - can you do me a favour? If you like the answer can you accept it or vote it up :)

Comment: I'm  new member and i don't have enough reputation to vote it up :/